# как изпользовать переменные из одного файла в другом

Tags: nginx, sh, yml

Есть файл, в нем прописано имя машинки

```
MACHINE_FQDN_VALUE=bla.bla.com
```

нужно использовать его в sh скрипте, yml файлах и конфиге nginx. Как это можно для каждого сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в sh пожалуйста:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /somedir/hostfile.txt
echo $MACHINE_FQDN_VALUE
```

в nginx можно через lua извратиться, что-то вроде:

```
file_data '
  local file = "/somedir/hostfile.txt"
  local f = io.open(file, "r")
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  ngx.print(content)
';
```

только что вы собираетесь делать с этим?

yml формат не поддерживает подгрузку данных из файла.

Comment: хм, спасибо)) а для yml мож есть вариант реплейса шаблона или вроде того? я просто в скриптах не шарю:(

Comment: Реплейс пожалуйста. Я думаю можно сделать новый вопрос с куском yml и описанием того, что нужно заменить. Я думаю пример  с sed-ом люди скинут.